# Why do Firefox and Chrome crash on my Macbook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, google-chrome, crash, firefox

I have trouble running Firefox and Chrome on my Mac.

Firefox is crashing from time to time:
http://pastebin.com/UYYjPbZe

Chrome crashes right after installation, it couldn't run it even once:
http://pastebin.com/3PQq88XC

Safari is running fine. I am not a Mac user, this is my first one but I'm starting to think Apple doesn't want to run other browser that won't be theirs. Could that be possible?